# Very strange jQuery selector bug in Firefox 3.6.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox-3

Alright, I spent a lot of time turning a non-AJAX shopping cart checkout into an AJAX checkout.

I did this by separating out the various sections into tabs using jQuery UI tabs.  I then use AJAX to post changes on one tab and selectively refresh other tabs.  The selective refresh simply grabs the result of the post and uses a jQuery selector to grab only the relevant div from the response.

In this particular case, a tab with shipping information is posting and refreshing a tab with a list of shipping methods.

This works flawlessly excepting one browser: Firefox 3.6.x (Mac and Windows)

In Firefox 3, the selector pulls back a truncated result from the result of the POST, which effectively removes crucial buttons and prevents the user from proceeding.

Here is the full html response, with formatting:

http://pastebin.com/aVF6yUba

EDIT: The above is apparently not 100% consistent with the actual output. Here is the truly RAW output:
http://pastebin.com/ChAT1vLf

Here is the relevant line of JavaScript:

```
jQuery("#shipping-method-section").html(output.html());
```

Here is what every other browser pulls back with that line:

```
<!--- shipping method section ---> 
<h2>Select a shipping method:</h2> 
<ul id="shipping-methods">
    <li><span><label><input name="shipmethod" value="FedEx+Priority+Overnight" class="shopp shipmethod" type="radio"> FedEx Priority Overnight — <strong>$30.68</strong> <span>Estimated Delivery:&nbsp;&nbsp;September 28, 2011</span> </label> </span> </li>
    <li> <span> <label><input name="shipmethod" value="FedEx+Standard+Overnight" class="shopp shipmethod" type="radio"> FedEx Standard Overnight — <strong>$26.46</strong> <span>Estimated Delivery:&nbsp;&nbsp;September 28, 2011</span> </label> </span> </li> 
    <li> <span> <label><input name="shipmethod" value="FedEx+2Day" class="shopp shipmethod" type="radio"> FedEx 2Day — <strong>$19.10</strong> <span>Estimated Delivery:&nbsp;&nbsp;September 29, 2011</span> </label> </span> </li> 
    <li> <span> <label><input name="shipmethod" value="FedEx+Express+Saver" class="shopp shipmethod" type="radio"> FedEx Express Saver — <strong>$18.79</strong> <span>Estimated Delivery:&nbsp;&nbsp;September 30, 2011</span> </label> </span> </li> 
    <li> <span> <label><input name="shipmethod" value="FedEx+Home+Delivery" class="shopp shipmethod" checked="checked" type="radio"> FedEx Home Delivery — <strong>$13.52</strong> <span>Estimated Delivery:&nbsp;&nbsp;September 27, 2011</span> </label> </span> </li> 
</ul> 
<hr> 
<div class="tab-back-button"> 
    <input class="tab-back-button" value="Shipping Address" type="button"> 
</div> 
<input value="Payment Method" name="shipping-method-section-button" class="shipping-method-section-button" type="button">
```

Here is what Firefox 3.6.x pulls back:

```
<h2>Select a shipping method:</h2> 
<ul id="shipping-methods">
    <li><span><label><input name="shipmethod" value="FedEx+Priority+Overnight" class="shopp shipmethod" type="radio"> FedEx Priority Overnight — <strong>$30.68</strong> <span>Estimated Delivery:&nbsp;&nbsp;September 28, 2011</span> </label> </span> </li>
    <li> <span> <label><input name="shipmethod" value="FedEx+Standard+Overnight" class="shopp shipmethod" type="radio"> FedEx Standard Overnight — <strong>$26.46</strong> <span>Estimated Delivery:&nbsp;&nbsp;September 28, 2011</span> </label> </span> </li> 
    <li> <span> <label><input name="shipmethod" value="FedEx+2Day" class="shopp shipmethod" type="radio"> FedEx 2Day — <strong>$19.10</strong> <span>Estimated Delivery:&nbsp;&nbsp;September 29, 2011</span> </label> </span> </li> 
    <li> <span> <label><input name="shipmethod" value="FedEx+Express+Saver" class="shopp shipmethod" type="radio"> FedEx Express Saver — <strong>$18.79</strong> <span>Estimated Delivery:&nbsp;&nbsp;September 30, 2011</span> </label> </span> </li> 
    <li> <span> <label><input name="shipmethod" value="FedEx+Home+Delivery" class="shopp shipmethod" checked="checked" type="radio"> FedEx Home Delivery — <strong>$13.52</strong> <span>Estimated Delivery:&nbsp;&nbsp;September 27, 2011</span> </label> </span> </li> 
</ul>
```

I can find no rhyme or reason to this.

As a temporary work around, I wrote some JavaScript that detects Firefox 3 and forces a full refresh to get them to the next tab.

Anyone have any ideas on how to make this work properly?

Thanks!
Clif

EDIT. Here is the full JavaScript:

```
jQuery.post( url, data, function(output) {
    if(error_check_passed(output, "FedEx"))
    {   
        jQuery("#shipping-section").css({ 'opacity' : 1.0 });
        update_cart_summary(output);

        hide_errors();
        output = jQuery("#shipping-method-section", jQuery(output));

        jQuery("#shipping-method-section").html(output.html());
        allowTabChange = true; 
        jQuery("#checkout-tabs").tabs('select', 1); 
    }
    else
    {   
        jQuery("#shipping-section").fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
        show_errors(output, "FedEx");
    }
});
```

Comment: I think that the "relevant line of JavaScript" is likely to be something involved with the AJAX interaction.  Also I assume you've checked the actual HTTP response with Firebug, etc.

Comment: What is `output` and where does it come from?

Comment: I included a minimum just to reduce the noise.  I've added the entire JavaScript block. Output is the raw data from the POST that I put in the PasteBin.  I have inspected it with FireBug, hence my knowledge of where the problem lies.

Comment: This is impossible to debug without being able to test the actual site (..unless someone is familiar with the problem).

Comment: http://www.mooreandgiles.com/bags  Add something to your cart, go to checkout.  Checkout as Guest.  It's the first step in the checkout process.  The file is checkout.js and the problem line is around 136.  Please note that my code to force refresh in Firefox 3 is in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the two `form` tags. I copied your pastebin and cut it down to the section that `shipping-method-section` is contained in, and it worked fine in ff3.6. I then added the sction that that section is in, which is a `form` section. It then broke. If you change the outer `form` section to anything other than that, it works fine. That's also why the inner form tag is being stripped out if you browse the `DOM` with firebug (in newer versions too). If you inspect your page in FF3.6 before a reload, when the buttons are showing correctly, I think you will find that the `hr` and all tags after it are outside the `shipping-method-selection` `div`

I realize the `form` section can't be changed, so I'm not sure what you could do to work around it. Nested forms [aren't allowed](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input), but I know a lot of people use them anyway with no problems.

--edit--

I looked at the site, and the `<hr>` and on is inside `shipping-method-section`. However, I took your whole pastebin and did this:

```
jQuery.post( 'testClifPost.html', function(output) {

    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.innerHTML = output;
    console.log(d);
}
```

In this output, `<hr>` is outside of `shipping-method-section`. This seems to say that it's not jQuery, but that firefox 3.6 parses things differently when javascript asks for it to parse something that when it loads it into the browser.

Comment: Asher, thanks for the feedback.  I'm investigating this right now as I found IE8 is having a weird issue as well.

Comment: The nested form was the problem. And, because Shopp is a bit generous in the way it processes requests, it ultimately didn't affect any functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may be that FF doesn't like the `<hr>` tag, and is breaking out there.  Have you tried it with `<hr />` instead of just `<hr>`  ?

Comment: This is absolutely not the problem.  The `<hr>` tag has worked fine, in both its XHTML self-closing version and as unclosed HTML, since forever.

Comment: It turns out the actual output has <hr />.  The tidy tool I ran to indent it for easy reading made that change. #@$%

Comment: I added another pastebin with the true raw output.